# Calculating $\langle\hat{\phi_i}\rangle_t$ (Blundell's Quantum field theory) (EDITED)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, partition-function

I am reading Blundell's Quantum field theory for the Gifted Amateur and stuck at some calculation. In his book p.197, 21.2 Sources in statistical physics, he defined the partition function with the source term by

$$Z(J)=\operatorname{Tr}[e^{-\beta\hat{H}}] := \operatorname{Tr}[e^{-\beta\hat{H_0}+\Sigma_kJ_k \hat{\phi_k}}]$$

Then he calculated the thermal average $\langle \hat{\phi_i} \rangle_t$ (c.f. his book p.197) by

$$\langle \hat{\phi_i} \rangle_t = \frac{1}{Z(J=0)}\frac{\partial Z(J)}{\partial(J_i)}|_{J_i=0} = \frac{\operatorname{Tr}[\hat{\phi_i}e^{-\beta\hat{H_0}}]}{Z(J=0)} $$

And why is the second equality true?

Perhaps,

$$\frac{\partial Z(J)}{\partial(J_i)}|_{J_i=0}=\operatorname{Tr}[e^{-\beta \hat{H_0}} \cdot 
 e^{\Sigma_{k} J_k \hat{\phi_k}} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial(J_i)}(\Sigma_k J_k \hat{\phi_k})]|_{J_i=0} = \operatorname{Tr}[e^{-\beta \hat{H_0}} \cdot e^{\Sigma_{k} J_k \hat{\phi_k}} \cdot \hat{\phi_i} ]|_{J_i=0}~? $$

True? If so, how about next step? Can anyone help?

Comment: Use MathJax, not screenshots/images. This was written under your last few question. Could you please follow our policies?

Comment: O.K. I edited. Perhaps, can you reopen my question?

Comment: That looks quite right to me, just set the source term to zero in the last term and then dividing by Z gives you the expectation value written as a trace. You should set all sources to 0, not just the i'th one normally.

Comment: Thank you. And.. Your comment is somewhat ambiguous to follow, What's the meaning of setting zero to all sources (not just the i'th one) in our calculation ? Perhaps, the author made mistake in some part?

Comment: I was not sure what your mistake would've been. The notation looks like you only set $J_i$ to zero. Maybe you thought that's not equal to setting all the sources to zero.

Comment: Yes. I thought that there is a difference between setting all sources to zero and setting $j_I$ to zero. Is there a  part that I confuse or made mistake? What is your opinion and gist? Perhaps, can you wrote calculation more in detail?